# What does NoSuchKey error mean while subscribing for notification in Ceph?

Tags: amazon-s3, notifications, ceph, radosgw

I am trying to follow this url https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/s3/bucketops/#create-notification

to create a publisher for my bucket into a topic.

My curl:

```
curl -v -H 'Date: Fri, 16 Apr 2021 05:21:14 +0000' -H 'Authorization: AWS accessid:secretkey' -L -H 'content-type: text/xml' -H 'Content-MD5: pBRX39Oo7aAUYbilIYMoAw==' -T notif.xml http://ceph:8080/vig-test?notification
```

and it returns me this error

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <BucketName>vig-test</BucketName>
  <RequestId>tx0000000000000016ac570-0060791ecb-1c7e96b-hkg</RequestId>
  <HostId>1c7e96b-hkg-data</HostId>
</Error>
```

Does anybody know what does this error mean in Ceph? How can I proceed?

Comment: May be [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3/) is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue myself. *NoSuchKey* means it cannot find the topic.

I should've created both the topic and bucket notification using same credentials.

But when creating the topic, it allowed me to create without any credential and ended up being created under anonymous user.

That is what has caused it to throw *NoSuchKey* error.